# Image from Firebase Storage doesn't refresh in my UIImageView (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have added a function where I can update the Profile-image (which is saved in the Firebase Storage + a link to it in the Firestore).
But, when I go back to the Profile View Controller, the Profile-image hasn't updated.
How can I solve this problem?

my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class testProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pfp: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        profilePicture()
    }

    func profilePicture(){
        pfp.layer.cornerRadius = pfp.frame.size.width / 2
        pfp.clipsToBounds = true

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://hdlrz-92bk4.appspot.com")
        let imageView: UIImageView = self.pfp

        let ref = storageRef.child("profileImages")

        imageView.sd_setImage(with: ref)

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a gs:// url in an ImageView.  gs:// URLs have a special meaning in Google Cloud, and don't make sense to applications.  What you should do instead is [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url), which will be a normal https:// type URL, and use that to display the image.